# Xscreensaver not locking automatically on OS Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, xscreensaver

I upgraded my operating system from 18.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS however after the upgade I wanted to use XSCREENSAVER instead of the default light or xfce, now when I copied all the configurations from 18.04 to 22.04 it works fine when I lock it myself however after a certain while when the screen locks itself the XSCREENSAVER doesnt work and it is taking the default one for lock, not sure why is it doing that? anyone who every tried this before?